# how can apply multiple data in php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

i have my on work but still error plz help me...

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
                $bfcp=$bfcp=$_POST['bfcp'];
                $casualwear=$_POST['casualwear'];
                $popularity=$_POST['popularity'];
                $formalwear=$_POST['formalwear'];
                $talent=$_POST['talent'];
                $questionandanswer=$_POST['questionandanswer'];
                $Total= $bfcp + $casualwear + $popularity + $formalwear + $talent + $questionandanswer;
$sql="INSERT INTO criteria (id, bfcp, casualwear, popularity, formalwear, talent, questionandanswer, Total)
values('$id','$bfcp','$casualwear','$popularity','$formalwear','$talent','$questionandanswer','$Total')
,('$id','$bfcp','$casualwear','$popularity','$formalwear','$talent','$questionandanswer','$Total')";mysql_query($sql,$conn)or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Plzz help me....

Comment: could you please paste the create statement of the tabl

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

Your query was wrong.Please use below

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
                $bfcp=$bfcp=$_POST['bfcp'];
                $casualwear=$_POST['casualwear'];
                $popularity=$_POST['popularity'];
                $formalwear=$_POST['formalwear'];
                $talent=$_POST['talent'];
                $questionandanswer=$_POST['questionandanswer'];
                $Total= $bfcp + $casualwear + $popularity + $formalwear + $talent + $questionandanswer;
$sql="INSERT INTO criteria (id, bfcp, casualwear, popularity, formalwear, talent, questionandanswer, Total)
values('$id','$bfcp','$casualwear','$popularity','$formalwear','$talent','$questionandanswer','$Total'");
mysql_query($sql,$conn)or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: coding can you help fixed my code to input multiple  data.... the code you give is one data only :(

Comment: multiple data in the sense ? can u give some example for that ?